# Change outbound IP - centos

Tags: linux, centos, networking, network-interface, routing

i have a server (linux/centos) and my default ip is:
111.111.111.111   so i bought another ip (ip failover) 222.222.222.222

*if i visit in browser 111.111.111.111 or 222.222.222.222 its opening same page*

so i have **eth0:**

```
UUID="2f99a6-6566-sb24-bd0e-bf5a8d4a1765"
IPADDR="111.111.111.111"
GATEWAY="111.111.111.1"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

also i created **eth0:0**

same as above just changed

```
DEVICE="eth0:0"
IPADDR="222.222.222.222"
#GATEWAY="111.111.111.1"(commented it)
```

when i run
**curl --interface eth0 ifconfig.co**    the response is 111.111.111.111

**curl --interface eth0:0 ifconfig.co**    the response is 222.222.222.222

but when i use wget or **ffmpeg**(i just want to find solution for ffmpeg )
then ip is 111.111.111.111

so how i can make **default** outbound IP to be *222.222.222.222* (its my second ip/ i bought as failover ip)

Comment: Welcome to this site! Can you elaborate a bit more on your setup? How are you connecting with ffmpeg? Usually, if you connect to `111.111.111.111` responses come from `111.111.111.111` and vice-versa with `222.222.222.222`. Are you connecting through an hostname maybe (which resolvs only to `111.111.111.111`)?

Comment: Please do not crosspost: https://serverfault.com/questions/929631/change-outbound-ip-centos

Answer (score 0):

Use this tiny lib with LD_PRELOAD:

```
/*
   Copyright (C) 2000  Daniel Ryde

   This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.
*/

/*
   LD_PRELOAD library to make bind and connect to use a virtual
   IP address as localaddress. Specified via the enviroment
   variable BIND_ADDR.

   Compile on Linux with:
   gcc -nostartfiles -fpic -shared bind.c -o bind.so -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE


   Example in bash to make inetd only listen to the localhost
   lo interface, thus disabling remote connections and only
   enable to/from localhost:

   BIND_ADDR="127.0.0.1" LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so /sbin/inetd


   Example in bash to use your virtual IP as your outgoing
   sourceaddress for ircII:

   BIND_ADDR="your-virt-ip" LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so ircII

   Note that you have to set up your servers virtual IP first.


   This program was made by Daniel Ryde
   email: daniel@ryde.net
   web:   http://www.ryde.net/

   TODO: I would like to extend it to the accept calls too, like a
   general tcp-wrapper. Also like an junkbuster for web-banners.
   For libc5 you need to replace socklen_t with int.
*/



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>

int (*real_bind)(int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);
int (*real_connect)(int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);

char *bind_addr_env;
unsigned long int bind_addr_saddr;
unsigned long int inaddr_any_saddr;
struct sockaddr_in local_sockaddr_in[] = { 0 };

void _init (void)
{
    const char *err;

    real_bind = dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "bind");
    if ((err = dlerror ()) != NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "dlsym (bind): %s\n", err);
    }

    real_connect = dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "connect");
    if ((err = dlerror ()) != NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "dlsym (connect): %s\n", err);
    }

    inaddr_any_saddr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind_addr_env = getenv ("BIND_ADDR")) {
        bind_addr_saddr = inet_addr (bind_addr_env);
        local_sockaddr_in->sin_family = AF_INET;
        local_sockaddr_in->sin_addr.s_addr = bind_addr_saddr;
        local_sockaddr_in->sin_port = htons (0);
    }
}

int bind (int fd, const struct sockaddr *sk, socklen_t sl)
{
    static struct sockaddr_in *lsk_in;

    lsk_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)sk;
/*  printf("bind: %d %s:%d\n", fd, inet_ntoa (lsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr),
        ntohs (lsk_in->sin_port));*/
        if ((lsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET)
        && (lsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr == inaddr_any_saddr)
        && (bind_addr_env)) {
        lsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr = bind_addr_saddr;
    }
    return real_bind (fd, sk, sl);
}

int connect (int fd, const struct sockaddr *sk, socklen_t sl)
{
    static struct sockaddr_in *rsk_in;

    rsk_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)sk;
/*  printf("connect: %d %s:%d\n", fd, inet_ntoa (rsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr),
        ntohs (rsk_in->sin_port));*/
        if ((rsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET)
        && (bind_addr_env)) {
        real_bind (fd, (struct sockaddr *)local_sockaddr_in, sizeof (struct sockaddr));
    }
    return real_connect (fd, sk, sl);
}
```

from http://www.ryde.net/code/